# C++ Linking a custom library built from source (CMakeLists.txt)

Tags: c++, cmake, makefile, open3d

1. I built Open3D from source into a /home/user/custom_location/Open3D/build
2. I have a project with a dependency on Open3D and a CMakeLists.txt like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.12)

project(graph_filter)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED True)
set(CMAKE_CXX_EXTENSIONS OFF)

# Pybind11
find_package(pybind11 REQUIRED)

# OpenMP
find_package(OpenMP REQUIRED)

# Eigen
find_package(Eigen3 3.3 REQUIRED NO_MODULE)

# Open3D
list(APPEND CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX "~/libraries/")
find_package(Open3D HINTS ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/lib/CMake)
list(APPEND Open3D_LIBRARIES dl)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} ${Open3D_CXX_FLAGS}")
set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS} ${Open3D_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS}")

include_directories(${Open3D_INCLUDE_DIRS})
link_directories(${Open3D_LIBRARY_DIRS})

pybind11_add_module(
    graph_filter
    wrapper.cpp
)
target_link_libraries(graph_filter PRIVATE ${Open3D_LIBRARIES} Eigen3::Eigen OpenMP::OpenMP_CXX)
```

3. **How can I link it?**  When I run

````
INSTALL_DIR=/home/user/custom_location/Open3D/build
cmake -S . -B build -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=${INSTALL_DIR}```
````

**I am getting:**

```
Could NOT find Open3D (missing: Open3D_DIR)
```

```
fatal error: Open3D/Open3D.h: No such file or directory
    2 | #include <Open3D/Open3D.h>
```

What is more confusing is the contents of Open3D/build folder after building from source.

**I just want to resolve this dependency on Open3D. Thanks for any help!!!**

Comment: Your error is not linking. It's a problem with the include path.

Comment: For `include_directories` and `link_directories` you probably want to switch to use the `target_include_directories` and `target_link_directories`

Comment: Can I use an absolute path with `target_include_directories` ?

Comment: Also, what about
` find_package(Open3D HINTS ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/lib/CMake)` Do I need to change anything here?

Comment: Sorry I am new to cmake. What does "${Open3D_INCLUDE_DIRS}" mean? I don't see it defined anywhere?!

Comment: The finder activated by find_package(...) for Open3D would initialize it. You can add `message(STATUS Open3D_INCLUDE_DIRS=${Open3D_INCLUDE_DIRS})` after `find_package(Open3D HINTS ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/lib/CMake)` to see what this variable contains. After you investigate this make sure that their is an `Open3D` folder inside so that the relative path `Open3D/Open3D.h` will be valid.

Comment: `find_package(Open3D)` almost certainly does require an installation of the build results. Check the instructions of the library for something like `cmake --install ...` or `make install`. You may want to install to a directory of your choice, e.g. `cmake --install build_dir --prefix ~/open3d_install`. Assuming this installs a file `open3dConfig.cmake` or `Open3D-Config.cmake` you need to pass the install prefix as (one of the) `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` (values) to the project trying to find the pacakge: `cmake -D CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/home/username/open3d_install -S source_dir -B build_dir_2`